# How to not trigger outside button when there are two div with onClick or button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I designed a div inside a div which contains my button, when click outside div, it will trigger switch page, and another div will do other function, and the thing is, when I click the button inside, it will also trigger the div onClick outside, the original code contains so many other stuffs, so I will write an example like below,

```html
<div className="outSide" onClick={()=>changePage}>
    <button onClick={dosomeotherthing)}>some Function</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Events in the DOM "bubble" from descendants to ancestors. You can control that with methods like [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: That's exactly what I expected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, when you click the button it should not fire the change page. You can try stopPropagation.

```
function dosomeotherthing(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
}

<div className="outSide" onClick={()=>changePage}>
  <button onClick={(e) => dosomeotherthing(e)}>some Function</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates.